# Android API level 30, Can't no longer get wifi network device MAC address from Android arp table

Tags: android, mac-address, arp, network-scan

I have a small network scanner app which needs to find MAC addresses for scanned devices which responds to ping and so on. Soon Google requires targetSdkVersion 30 meaning that cannot no longer access arp table in any way without response:

> Permission denied

Previously I used:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
```

and then later workaround with API29:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ip neighbor");
process.waitFor();
```

but now I no longer find any way to solve this problem when targetSdkVersion 30 becomes mandatory to get updates into Play Store.

I have read Googles documentations why in privacy reasons this happens so no need to explain that part.

Does anyone have any ideas or is network scanning apps basically doomed forever?